# Nodejs sequelize bulk upsert

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way of doing bulk upsert in sequelize. Also, can I specify which keys to use for checking for duplicates?

I tried following but it didn't work:

```
Employee.bulkCreate(data, {
    updateOnDuplicate: true
});
```

Bulk creation works fine though. Above statement always creates new entries in the DB.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

From the official [sequelizejs reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate).

It can be done using `bulkCreate` with the `updateOnDuplicate` option.

Like this for example :

```
Employee.bulkCreate(dataArray, 
    {
        fields:["id", "name", "address"] ,
        updateOnDuplicate: ["name"] 
    } )
```

`updateOnDuplicate` is an array of fields that will be updated when the primary key (or may be unique key) match the row. Make sure you have at least one unique field (let say id) in your model and in the `dataArray` both for upsert.

Comment: Thanks followtest52, bingo :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation says that this option is supported only by mysql =(

Comment: if you set a boolean true  like: ```updateOnDuplicate: true ``` all attributes will be updated if changed.

Comment: Now Postgres supported also - "Fields to update if row key already exists (on duplicate key update)? (only supported by MySQL, MariaDB & Postgres >= 9.5). By default, all fields are updated."

Comment: Worth mentioning: the field `updatedAt` which is usually automagically updated by sequelize will _not_ get updated unless it's explicitly passed via `updateOnDuplicate`

Comment: A note: if your table has uniq indexes, this solution won't work. A PR is in progress: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12516

Comment: "By default, all fields are updated." so does that mean you could leave the option out and it would do an upsert by default?

Comment: This accepted answer doesn't work in all cases. It doesn't work with unique composite indexes yet.

Comment: SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 "sequelize": "^6.6.5"

Comment: can you more explain how to retrive status its create is true / false i mean state of execution is create or update .

Comment: Do not forget to mark the field as unique `@Unique decorator in case of sequelize-typescript` otherwise this code will try to use primary key instead of `name`. Postgres 14.1

Comment: Just stumbled upon this, if anyone comes here looking out for more info,

Make sure you have a column that has unique Index. Sometimes primary key is something you can't use. eg.

id, name and age here you can have index on id but for data insertion you can't use it to find duplicate so just make name as unique index and it will work.

Answer (score 15):

### Update (Sequelize >= 6)

Sequelize 6.x added support for all UPSERTs on all dialects, so @followtest52's answer is valid for PostgreSQL too.

### Original (Sequelize < 6)

Since PostgreSQL is not supported by the answer, the """"best"""" alternative using Sequelize is doing a manual query with the [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html#on_conflict) statement. Example (Typescript):

```
const values: Array<Array<number | string>> = [
    [1, 'Apple', 'Red', 'Yummy'],
    [2, 'Kiwi', 'Green', 'Yuck'],
]

const query = 'INSERT INTO fruits (id, name, color, flavor) VALUES ' +
     values.map(_ => { return '(?)' }).join(',') +
     ' ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET flavor = excluded.flavor;'

sequelize.query({ query, values }, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT })
```

This would build a query like:

```
INSERT INTO 
    fruits (id, name, color, flavor)
VALUES 
    (1, 'Apple', 'Red', 'Yummy'),
    (2, 'Kiwi', 'Green', 'Yuck')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET 
    flavor = excluded.flavor;
```

Suffice to say, this is not an ideal solution to have to  manually build queries, since it defeats the purpose of using sequelize, but if it's one-off query that you don't desperately need, you could use this method.

Comment: Do not forget to mark the field as unique `@Unique decorator in case of sequelize-typescript` otherwise this code will try to use primary key instead of `name`. Postgres 14.1

Answer (score 7):

**2019 Update**

Works for all dialects provided a certain minimum version is matched

[HERE](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js#L2532) is the reference to the source code for the same

- Note that individual options may or may not work across all dialects
  For example, updateOnDuplicate will work only on MySQL, MariaDB,
  SQLite and Postgres
- ignoreDuplicates option will NOT work on MSSQL

Also check this BLOCK of code in the source

```
if (Array.isArray(options.updateOnDuplicate) && options.updateOnDuplicate.length) {
    options.updateOnDuplicate = _.intersection(
        _.without(Object.keys(model.tableAttributes), createdAtAttr),
        options.updateOnDuplicate
    );
} else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('updateOnDuplicate option only supports non-empty array.'));
}
```

updateOnDuplicate has to be an Array, cannot be true or false

So going with the above points, your code should be something like this

```
Employee.bulkCreate(data, {
    updateOnDuplicate: ['employeeName', 'employeeAge'],
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Since someone mentioned it is not working, try this

```
models.Employee.bulkCreate(items, {
    returning: ['employeeId'],
    ignoreDuplicates: true
  })
```

Comment: items should be an array of objects with the same fields your model has

Comment: Your update will work for situations when you don't need to update values. It is a nice way in postgres to say "if this doesn't exist, make it ... but if it does exist, don't change anything about it." I can use this for part of my problem now. But I still need to (a) update row fields on "duplicates" and then create those rows if they do not exist. Trying to avoid raw SQL.

Comment: did you try this updateOnDuplicate: ['employeeName', 'employeeAge'] it works on my table

Comment: That's so weird it's working for you. I am using heroku postgres with the latest version of sequelize. When I use Page.bulkCreate(data.pages, { returning: true, updateOnDuplicate: ['id'] }), it will create new instances, but it won't update the old ones.

Comment: what is your sequelize version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203563/discussion-between-rob-and-pirateapp).

Comment: I get this error `there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification` in a model that has a primary key of `id` and 4 other attributes that have a unique constraint. Anybody else has run into this?

Answer (score 5):

***2020 October 1st Update***
Sequelize Version: ^6.3.5

**The issue still persists.** We can't still `bulkUpsert` with unique composite indexes. `bulkCreate` with `updateOnDuplicates` doesn't yet work with unique composite indexes. There are PR's still awaiting to be merged, which may fix this issue:-
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12516
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12547

#### Workaround

For the time being, if anyone wants a quick workaround, then the following raw query based wrapper can be used by modifying with your own tables attributes, names and data:-

```js
const bulkUpsertIntoTable = async ({ bulkUpsertableData }) => {
  try {
    /* eslint-disable */
   // id column will automatically be incremented if you have set it to auto-increment
   const query = `INSERT INTO "Table" ("non_id_attr1", "non_id_attr2", "non_id_attr3","createdAt", "updatedAt") VALUES ${bulkUpsertableData
    .map((_) => "(?)")
    .join(
      ","
    )} ON CONFLICT ("non_id_attr1","non_id_attr2") DO UPDATE SET "non_id_attr1"=excluded."non_id_attr1", "non_id_attr2"=excluded."non_id_attr2", "non_id_attr3"=excluded."non_id_attr3",  "updatedAt"=excluded."updatedAt" RETURNING "id","non_id_attr1","non_id_attr2","non_id_attr3","createdAt","updatedAt";`;
    /* eslint-enable */

    return await models.sequelize.query(query, {
      replacements: bulkUpsertableData,//------> dont forget to pass your data here
      type: models.Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT,
      // transaction:t -----> if required to be done in transaction
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Bulk Upserting into Table:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**Important point is creating the `bulkUpsertableData`**, where it should be `Array<Array> ie:- [[]]`. Example creation:-

```js
// with reference to above wrapper function
const bulkUpsertableData = Object.keys(myObjectData).map(type => [
      myObjectData[type],// -----> non_id_attr1
      type, // -----> non_id_attr2
      someOtherRandomValue, // -----> non_id_attr3
      new Date(), // -----> created_at
      new Date(), // -----> updated_at
]);

// response will have all the raw attributes mentioned in RETURNING clause
const upsertedTableResponse = await bulkUpsertIntoTable({ bulkUpsertableData });
```

Comment: Thanks @Yedhin for this answer I will post a more generic solution based on your code.

Answer (score 2):

**2020 November 2nd update**

Based on @Yedhin answer, here is a more generic solution (typescript):

```
export const bulkUpsert = async <T extends Model<T>, K extends keyof T>(
  items: Partial<T>[],
  model: ModelCtor<T>,
  conflictKeys: K[],
  excludeFromUpdate: K[] = [],
): Promise<[number, number]> => {
  if (!items.length) {
    return [0, 0];
  }

  const { tableName, sequelize, name } = model;
  if (!sequelize) {
    throw new Error(`Sequelize not initialized on ${name}?`);
  }

  const sample = items[0];
  const fields = Object.keys(sample) as K[];
  const createFields = `("${fields.join(`","`)}")`;
  const updateFields = fields
    .filter((field) => ![...excludeFromUpdate, ...conflictKeys].includes(field))
    .map((field) => `"${field}"=EXCLUDED."${field}"`)
    .join(', ');
  const values = items.map(dataToSql(sequelize)).join(',');
  const onConflict = `ON CONFLICT ("${conflictKeys.join(`","`)}")`;
  const returning = `"${fields.join('","')}"`;

  const query = `INSERT INTO "${tableName}" ${createFields} VALUES ${values} ${onConflict} DO UPDATE SET ${updateFields} RETURNING ${returning};`;

  return sequelize.query(query, {
    replacements: items,
    type: QueryTypes.INSERT,
  });
};

const valueToSql = (sequelize: Sequelize) => (
  value: string | number | boolean | null | Date | string[] | Record<string, unknown>,
): string => {
  if (value === null) {
    return 'null';
  }

  if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
    return value ? 'true' : 'false';
  }

  if (typeof value !== 'object' || value instanceof Date) {
    return sequelize.escape(value);
  }

  return sequelize.escape(JSON.stringify(value));
};


const dataToSql = <T extends Node<T>>(sequelize: Sequelize) => (data: Partial<T>): string =>
  `(${Object.values(data).map(valueToSql(sequelize)).join(',')})`;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using `queryInterface.bulkInsert`, you will need to add an `upsertKeys` array in the options.
Example:

```
Employee.bulkCreate(dataArray, 
    {
        upsertKeys:["id"] ,
        updateOnDuplicate: ["name"] 
    } )
```

Answer (score 0):

**2021 September update**

Bulk upserting with unique compound indexes now just works in Sequelize v6.4.4.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/13345

Comment: How do I actually use the composite indexes and specify what keys I want to use to determine duplicates? It looks like there's an attribute called `upsertKeys` you can pass `bulkCreate`, is that correct? I was looking here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/13345/commits/9c28aa0f296bc3b4bb2b1d2a24cf1f4d4f299c14

Comment: Also is `updateOnDuplicate` supposed to be an array still? That's what the docs say but I thought it was supposed to be a boolean

Answer (score 0):

A modified version. Which would do the job.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {*} data Raw JSON data
 * @param {*} model Sequalize model
 * @param {*} fields Columns thare need to be inserted/update.If none passed, it will extract fields from the data.
 * @returns response consists of data with type of action(upsert/create) performed for each record.
 */
export const bulkUpert = (data, model, fields = undefined) => {
  console.log("****Bulk insertion started****");
  if (!data.length) {
    return [0, 0];
  }
  const { name, primaryKeyAttributes } = model;

  console.log(name, primaryKeyAttributes, fields);

  if (!sequelize) {
    throw new Error(`Sequalize not initialized on ${name}`);
  }

  const extractFields = fields ? fields : Object.keys(data[0]);
  const createFields = extractFields.join(", ");
  const values = data.map(dataToSql()).join(", ");

  const query = `MERGE INTO
    [${name}]
    WITH(HOLDLOCK)
    AS [targetTable]
    USING (
        VALUES ${values}
    )
    AS [sourceTable]
    (
      ${createFields}
    ) ON
    ${getPrimaryQueryString(primaryKeyAttributes)}
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            ${getUpdateFieldsString(extractFields)}
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
              ${createFields}
            )
        VALUES
            (
                ${getInsertValuesString(extractFields)}
            )
    OUTPUT $action, INSERTED.*;`;
  return sequelize.query(query);
};

const valueToSQL = () => (value) => {
  if (value === null) {
    return "null";
  }

  if (typeof value === "boolean") {
    return value ? "true" : "false";
  }

  if (typeof value !== "object" || value instanceof Date) {
    return sequelize.escape(value);
  }

  return sequelize.escape(JSON.stringify(value));
};

const getPrimaryQueryString = (primaryKeyAttributes) => {
  let string = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < primaryKeyAttributes.length; i++) {
    string += `[targetTable].[${primaryKeyAttributes[i]}] = [sourceTable].[${primaryKeyAttributes[i]}]`;
    if (i != primaryKeyAttributes.length - 1) {
      string += " AND";
    }
  }
  return string;
};

const getUpdateFieldsString = (fields) => {
  let string = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    string += `[targetTable].[${fields[i]}] = [sourceTable].[${fields[i]}]`;
    if (i != fields.length - 1) {
      string += ", ";
    }
  }
  return string;
};

const getInsertValuesString = (fields) => {
  let string = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    string += `[sourceTable].[${fields[i]}]`;
    if (i != fields.length - 1) {
      string += ", ";
    }
  }
  return string;
};

const dataToSql = () => (data) =>
  `(${Object.values(data).map(valueToSQL()).join(",")})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone using `seqeulize` with `sequlize-typescript` if `updateOnDuplicate` is not working for an `unique` column, try to move your `unique` column up when declaring your `model`:

**Before**:

```
@Table({ modelName: 'transaction' })
export class TransactionModel extends Model {


  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  })
  override id: number;

  @Column(DataType.DATE)
  override createdAt: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  contractAddress: string;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  cumulativeGasUsed: number;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  from: string;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  gasUsed: number;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  effectiveGasPrice: number;


  @Column(DataType.TEXT)
  logsBloom: string;

  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  status: boolean;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  to: string;

  @Unique
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  hash: string;           // <---------------------- Required Unique column
}
```

**After:**

```
@Table({ modelName: 'transaction' })
export class TransactionModel extends Model {

  @Unique
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  hash: string;           // <---------------------- Required Unique column

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  })
  override id: number;

  @Column(DataType.DATE)
  override createdAt: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  contractAddress: string;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  cumulativeGasUsed: number;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  from: string;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  gasUsed: number;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  effectiveGasPrice: number;


  @Column(DataType.TEXT)
  logsBloom: string;

  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  status: boolean;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  to: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on @François Dispaux answer, I have improved the bulkUpsert function.

This should work with Sequelize and Postgres.

Notes: I have got some lines of code from source of sequelize library.

```
// Version: 6.17.0
// yarn add sequelize@6.17.0
//

const _ = require('lodash');
const { Sequelize, Model, Utils, QueryTypes, QueryError } = require('sequelize');

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------------------
const __defProp = Object.defineProperty;
const __defProps = Object.defineProperties;
const __getOwnPropDescs = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors;
const __getOwnPropSymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols;
const __hasOwnProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
const __propIsEnum = Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable;
const __defNormalProp = (obj, key, value) => key in obj ? __defProp(obj, key, { enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true, value }) : obj[key] = value;
const __spreadValues = (a, b) => {
  for (let prop in b || (b = {}))
    if (__hasOwnProp.call(b, prop))
      __defNormalProp(a, prop, b[prop]);
  if (__getOwnPropSymbols)
    for (let prop of __getOwnPropSymbols(b)) {
      if (__propIsEnum.call(b, prop))
        __defNormalProp(a, prop, b[prop]);
    }
  return a;
};
const __spreadProps = (a, b) => __defProps(a, __getOwnPropDescs(b));
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * 
 * @param {Model} model Instance of Sequelize model
 * @param {Object} options Similar to options of findAll function.
 * @param {Boolean} removeSemicolon to remove the semicolon at the end of query. It is useful when using to build query for UNION ALL
 * @returns {String} SQL SELECT query
 */
async function buildFindAllSQL(model, options, { removeSemicolon = false }) {
  if (options !== void 0 && !_.isPlainObject(options)) {
    throw new QueryError("The argument passed to findAll must be an options object, use findByPk if you wish to pass a single primary key value");
  }
  if (options !== void 0 && options.attributes) {
    if (!Array.isArray(options.attributes) && !_.isPlainObject(options.attributes)) {
      throw new QueryError("The attributes option must be an array of column names or an object");
    }
  }
  model.warnOnInvalidOptions(options, Object.keys(model.rawAttributes));
  const tableNames = {};
  tableNames[model.getTableName(options)] = true;
  options = Utils.cloneDeep(options);
  _.defaults(options, { hooks: true });
  options.rejectOnEmpty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(options, "rejectOnEmpty") ? options.rejectOnEmpty : model.options.rejectOnEmpty;
  model._injectScope(options);
  if (options.hooks) {
    await model.runHooks("beforeFind", options);
  }
  model._conformIncludes(options, model);
  model._expandAttributes(options);
  model._expandIncludeAll(options);
  if (options.hooks) {
    await model.runHooks("beforeFindAfterExpandIncludeAll", options);
  }
  options.originalAttributes = model._injectDependentVirtualAttributes(options.attributes);
  if (options.include) {
    options.hasJoin = true;
    model._validateIncludedElements(options, tableNames);
    if (options.attributes && !options.raw && model.primaryKeyAttribute && !options.attributes.includes(model.primaryKeyAttribute) && (!options.group || !options.hasSingleAssociation || options.hasMultiAssociation)) {
      options.attributes = [model.primaryKeyAttribute].concat(options.attributes);
    }
  }
  if (!options.attributes) {
    options.attributes = Object.keys(model.rawAttributes);
    options.originalAttributes = model._injectDependentVirtualAttributes(options.attributes);
  }
  model.options.whereCollection = options.where || null;
  Utils.mapFinderOptions(options, model);
  options = model._paranoidClause(model, options);
  if (options.hooks) {
    await model.runHooks("beforeFindAfterOptions", options);
  }
  const selectOptions = __spreadProps(__spreadValues({}, options), { tableNames: Object.keys(tableNames) });

  // This function based-on the code from findAll function of the Model class.
  // In the findAll function, the model.queryInterface.select function will be called.
  // Inside the select function of the QueryInterface class will define the way to build SELECT query.
  const sql = model.sequelize.queryInterface.queryGenerator.selectQuery(model.getTableName(selectOptions), { ...selectOptions, type: QueryTypes.SELECT, model }, model);

  if (removeSemicolon) {
    const lastChar = sql.slice(sql.length - 1);
    if (lastChar === ';') {
      return sql.slice(0, -1)
    }
  }

  return sql;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {Array<Object>} items List data object need to be parsed / mapped.
 * @param {Model} model Instance of Sequelize model
 * @param {Array<String>} fields List of columns' name
 * @returns {Array<Object>}
 */
function mapValues(items, { model, fields }) {
  const records = _.cloneDeep(items);
  //
  const fieldMappedAttributes = {};
  for (const attr in model.tableAttributes) {
    fieldMappedAttributes[model.rawAttributes[attr].field || attr] = model.rawAttributes[attr];
  }
  //
  const fieldValueHashes = records.map(values => {
    const out = Utils.mapValueFieldNames(values, fields, model);
    for (const key of model._virtualAttributes) {
      delete out[key];
    }
    return out;
  });
  //
  const tuples = []
  for (const fieldValueHash of fieldValueHashes) {
    const values = fields.map(key => {
      return model.sequelize.queryInterface.queryGenerator.escape(fieldValueHash[key], fieldMappedAttributes[key], { context: 'INSERT' });
    });
    tuples.push(`(${values.join(',')})`);
  }
  //
  return tuples;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {Array<Object>} items List data object need to be inserted / updated
 * @param {Model} model Instance of Sequelize model
 * @returns {String} SQL INSERT query
 */
async function buildBulkUpsertSQL(items = [], {
  model,
  conflictKeys = [],
  excludeFromUpdate = [],
  conflictWhere = [],
  returning = false,
  logging = false,
}) {

  if (!items.length) {
    return null;
  }

  const { tableName, sequelize } = model;

  const sample = items[0];
  const fields = Object.keys(sample);
  const createFields = `("${fields.join(`","`)}")`;
  const updateFields = fields
    .filter((field) => ![...excludeFromUpdate, ...conflictKeys].includes(field))
    .map((field) => `"${field}"=EXCLUDED.${field}`)
    .join(', ');
  //
  const tuples = mapValues(_.cloneDeep(items), { model, fields });
  const values = tuples.join(',');
  //
  const onConflict = `ON CONFLICT ("${conflictKeys.join(`","`)}")`;
  const returningFields = `"${fields.join('","')}"`;

  // const updateWhere = Object.keys(conflictWhere).length > 0 ? `WHERE ${Object.keys(conflictWhere).map(key => `"${tableName}"."${key}" ${conflictWhere[key]}`).join(',')}` : '';

  const updateWhere = conflictWhere.length > 0 ? `WHERE ${conflictWhere.join(',')}` : '';

  let query = `INSERT INTO "${tableName}" ${createFields} VALUES ${values}`;

  if (conflictKeys.length > 0) {
    query = `${query} ${onConflict} DO UPDATE SET ${updateFields} ${updateWhere}`;
  }

  if (returning === true) {
    query = `${query} RETURNING ${returningFields}`;
  }

  query += ';';

  if (typeof logging === 'function') {
    logging('---------------------------------------');
    logging(query);
    logging('---------------------------------------');
  }

  return query;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {Array<Object>} items List data object need to be inserted / updated
 * @param {Model} model Instance of Sequelize model
 * @returns {Array} Result of sequelize.query function
 */
async function bulkUpsert(items = [], {
  model,
  conflictKeys = [],
  excludeFromUpdate = [],
  conflictWhere = [],
  transaction = null,
  logging = false
}) {

  if (!items.length) {
    return [0, 0];
  }

  const query = await buildBulkUpsertSQL(items, { model, conflictKeys, excludeFromUpdate, conflictWhere, logging });

  if (!query) {
    return [0, 0];
  }

  const { sequelize } = model;

  const options = {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT,
    // logging,
  };

  if (transaction) {
    options[transaction] = transaction;
  }

  return sequelize.query(query, options);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = {
  buildFindAllSQL,
  buildBulkUpsertSQL,
  bulkUpsert,
  mapValues,
};
```