# Sequelize bulkCreate updateOnDuplicate for postgresQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I know there is no support for updateOnDuplicate for postgresQL by Sequelize [sequelize doc](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/sequelize/sequelize/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate), so is there a work around for this?

Can it be implemented via "SQL command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some work around. See [upsert](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/sequelize/sequelize/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert) function. When used in Postgresql it creates custom function in database. Unfortunately there is no `bulkUpsert`, so you either use it in some for-loop or execute raw SQL as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124949/nodejs-sequelize-bulk-upsert#answer-54082022).

Answer (score 5):

New sequelize (v5) includes updateOnDuplicate feature for all dialects

> Fields to update if row key already exists (on duplicate key update)?
>   (only supported by MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite >= 3.24.0 & Postgres >=
>   9.5). By default, all fields are updated.

Check here : [Docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)

You can use as

```
model.bulkCreate(dataToUpdate, { updateOnDuplicate: ["user_id", "token", "created_at"] })
```