# Sequelize Postgres - How to use ON CONFLICT for unique?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am implementing `sequelize` into my NodeJS application. Before this, I was using a written INSERT query that used `ON CONFLICT (field) DO NOTHING` to handle not inserting records where a value needed to be unique.

```
const sql = 'INSERT INTO communications (firstname, lastname, age, department, campus, state, message_uuid) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) ON CONFLICT (message_uuid) DO NOTHING';

const values = [val.firstName, val.lastName, val.age, val.department, val.campus, val.state, message_uuid];
```

Is there support for this in sequelize where I can define the same thing within a model? Or perhaps a better way to handle it?

Essentially, if a record already exists in the table in the column with `message_uuid` = 123 and another record try's to insert that has that same value, it ignores it and does nothing.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm wondering how to do the same.

Comment: There's also `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` support with `updateOnDuplicate`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531860/sequelize-bulkcreate-updateonduplicate-for-postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [public static bulkCreate(records: Array, options: Object): Promise<Array>](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate) method with `options.ignoreDuplicates`.

> Ignore duplicate values for primary keys? (not supported by MSSQL or Postgres < 9.5)

Besides, it's important to add a `unique` constraint for the `message_uuid` field on the model. So that the query will use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` clause of Postgres.

For example, `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"` and `postgres:9.6`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

class Communication extends Model {}
Communication.init(
  {
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
    age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    message_uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, tableName: 'communications' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await Communication.create({ firstname: 'teresa', lastname: 'teng', age: 32, message_uuid: 123 });
    // test
    await Communication.bulkCreate([{ firstname: 'teresa', lastname: 'teng', age: 32, message_uuid: 123 }], {
      ignoreDuplicates: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

Execution result:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "communications" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "communications" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "communications" ("id"   SERIAL , "firstname" VARCHAR(255), "lastname" VARCHAR(255), "age" INTEGER, "message_uuid" INTEGER UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'communications' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "communications" ("id","firstname","lastname","age","message_uuid") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "communications" ("id","firstname","lastname","age","message_uuid") VALUES (DEFAULT,'teresa','teng',32,123) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING *;
```

Check the database, there is only one row as expected.

```
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from communications;
 id | firstname | lastname | age | message_uuid 
----+-----------+----------+-----+--------------
  1 | teresa    | teng     |  32 |          123
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

see the new **UPSERT** feature in Sequelize **v6**:

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-upsert](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-upsert)

**Implementation details:**

> - MySQL - Implemented with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
> - PostgreSQL - Implemented with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE.
>   If update data contains PK field, then PK is selected as the default conflict
>   key. Otherwise first unique constraint/index will be selected, which
>   can satisfy conflict key requirements.
> - SQLite - Implemented with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
> - MSSQL - Implemented as a single query using MERGE and WHEN (NOT) MATCHED THEN

Answer (score -2):

as second argument of `Model.create` you can provide `onConflict` prop, please read the documentation

Comment: Here's github search results for "onConflict" within sequelize source code: https://github.com/search?l=&q=onConflict++repo%3Asequelize%2Fsequelize&type=Code Here's proof something like it exists, though: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/dialects/postgres/index.js#L45